# How to make geoserver return JSON for WMS GetFeatureInfo?

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I wish to get the results of a WMS GetFeatureInfo request as a JSON instead of the table that comes up by default.  Out of the box, the only options for the response from a WMS GetFeatureInfo are the table, XML and text.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**
The  'hack' given below is necessary only for Geoserver versions 2.2.x and below. With version [2.3.0](http://blog.geoserver.org/2013/03/18/geoserver-2-3-0-released-first-official-osgeo-release/) and upwards, Geoserver can return JSON for WMS GetFeatureInfo request natively.

*End of Update*

---

There is an open feature request for this on [geoserver's bug tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-1294).

Using custom [GetFeatureInfo Templates](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html#tutorials-getfeatureinfo), it is possible to generate a Json response from Geoserver.

You can follow these steps:

1]Go to the following folder

> GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/workspaces/{workspace}/{datastore}/{featuretype}/

2] Create 3 empty text files with the following names: 
*header.ftl, content.ftl & footer.ftl*

3] Open the content.ftl file, and copy the following [free-marker](http://www.freemarker.org/docs/index.html) code:

```
[
<#list features as feature>
{ "Type": "${type.name}"
<#list feature.attributes as attribute>
    <#if !attribute.isGeometry>
    , "${attribute.name}": "${attribute.value}"
    </#if>
</#list>
}
</#list> ,{}
]
```

4] Save the file and now make the WMS getFeatureInfo request. You'll see that the response is in JSON.

***Note:*** You need to remember that this will wrap the numeric values in inverted commas as a string. Hence you might have to take care of it in the client code.

Comment: Any idea why the documentation nowadays [claims _"Note outputFormat=json is only supported for getFeature (for backward compatibility)"_](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html)?

Comment: To answer my own silly question in the comment above: that note is only about the difference between `application/json` and just `json`. So, JSON is supported just fine, it's just that one should use `outputFormat=application/json`.

Answer (score 3):

This capability now exists in GeoServer 2.2.4.

Here's how to request JSON output:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know that this is finally available. Unfortunately I am still on an older version, and will be at that for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

I made this code for json ftl template, based in a post:

This is the code for header.ftl

```
[
```

This is the code for content.ftl:

```
{
"layer": "${type.name}",
"features": 
[
    <#list features as feature>
    {
        <#list feature.attributes as attribute>
            <#if !attribute.isGeometry>
                "${attribute.name?capitalize?js_string}": "${attribute.value?js_string}"<#if attribute_has_next>,</#if>
            </#if>
        </#list>
    }
    <#if feature_has_next>,</#if>
    </#list>
]
},
```

And this is for footer.ftl:

```
]
```

That is it!  The parsers will ignore the last comma in every last json object.

It work's for me.