# JSON format unavailable for GetFeatureInfo service

Tags: geoserver, wms, json

I have Geoserver 2.2.4 installed - [which allows GetFeatureInfo to be returned as json](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo)

If I make the following call

http://[servername]/geoserver/[namespace]/wms?LAYERS=[layername]&QUERY_LAYERS[layername]&STYLES=&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=299856.403448%2C528892.700948%2C300279.736552%2C529316.034052&FEATURE_COUNT=10&HEIGHT=600&WIDTH=600&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&INFO_FORMAT=application%2Fjson&SRS=EPSG%3A27700&X=249&Y=447&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fjson

I get a exception response of

Invalid format 'application/json', supported formats are [text/plain, application/vnd.ogc.gml, application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1, text/html]

I have checked getcapabilities for this service and only the following are available

```
<GetFeatureInfo>
    <Format>text/plain</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1</Format>
    <Format>text/html</Format>
</GetFeatureInfo>
```

So is there any extra config I need to do to Geoserver to get it to output in json for GetFeatureInfo?

Comment: Do you use a template for GetFeaturesInfo? http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html

Comment: Are you sure it is supported in 2.2.4? The following bug report says that it is fixed in 2.2.5? (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-1294)

Comment: I think Devdatta might be right. I was never able to get a JSON response running 2.2.4

Comment: @Devdatta Is 2.2.5 available?

Comment: @Mapperz I am aware you can use templates, I wanted to be able to request json format

Comment: I don't think that 2.2.5 is available. Check out this question though: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/how-to-make-geoserver-return-json-for-wms-getfeatureinfo

Comment: Seems strange to have it in the documentation for 2.2.x if it is not available in the latest stable version?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe thank you for confirming that this feature is not available yet, I will use the template solution for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be that despite documentation saying the the JSON output for GetFeatureInfo is available in 2.2.4, it will not be available until a future version.