# How to use XML data retrieved from WMS GetFeatureInfo?

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo

I use WMS layer in my app and could successfully retrieved Feature Info by click like so: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/getfeatureinfo-control.html

My question is: Is there any way to export the retrieved data in separate variables? So that I can organize the popup instead id this table. I see that its an XML file but still can't find a way to handle it.

Comment: What is your server? Are you using Geoserver of MapServer? if so which version?

Comment: Yes, GeoServer 2.2.3

Comment: If you can upgrade to version 2.3.0 or higher, than you can get native JSON output.  Otherwise you can try this 'hack' http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/how-to-make-geoserver-return-json-for-wms-getfeatureinfo

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set

format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML(),   // Used to parse the feature info response

infoFormat: 'application/vnd.ogc.gml', // Used to require the WMS server to provide GML format

When you set up your getfeatureinfo control. This should provide the information in a JavaScript variable you can interact with (event.features).