# How to get the result of WMS GetFeatureInfo request result into an array?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I am using OpenLayers 2.1.3 and using OpenLayers I obtain the GetFeatureInfo result but it is a web page, I want to get the output fields into a variable so I can display them in grid.

Answer (score 1):

Can you update your version of Geoserver? Newer (2.4+) versions of [Geoserver support JSON](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#getfeatureinfo) Natively for the response from the getFeatureInfo operation.

If you can't update you have two options:

1. Request for the output in GML and then parse the result in your Client code.
2. Otherwise, you can use [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44734/how-to-make-geoserver-return-json-for-wms-getfeatureinfo/44735#44735) 'hack' to get the response in JSON.

Once you have the results in your client code, you can then create an array and add the values to it.

Comment: there  is other problem too, when i call                    var request = OpenLayers.Request.GET({        url: url,       callback: handler        });                                                          there is an error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load (url) No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://(IP address)' is therefore not allowed access.What i need to do i googled it and found cross domain error, but when i put url in browser it works fine.What is that I am missing?and i tried your hack but the result is same as plain/html.(why so)?

Comment: @user3301246 That error is because of the Geoserver being on a differnt domain than your Application. You need a Proxy for this. Just look at these [search results](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=openLayers+Proxy+is%3AQuestion)

Comment: I have resolved it now i m not getting above XMLRequest Acess-Allow_Origin error but what i get from response.text is the text of proxy php file, I want to get the data of url which comes from getfeature info request.Thanks for your help